# Playing audio on page load and pausing it onClick

Tags: jquery

I am creating a page, which onload, plays the audio and when the user is listening to the track, they can pause it whenever they want to on click.

Below is my code.

**The HTML:**

```
<audio id="player" src="http://www.soundjay.com/ambient/check-point-1.mp3"></audio>
<a class="soundIcnPlay" title="button" id="button">&nbsp;</a>
```

**The jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = false;

    $('a#button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("down");

        if (playing == false) {
            document.getElementById('player').play();
            playing = true;
            $(this).removeClass('soundIcnPlay');
            $(this).addClass('soundIcnPause');

        } else {
            document.getElementById('player').pause();
            playing = false;
            $(this).removeClass('soundIcnPause');
            $(this).addClass('soundIcnPlay');
        }


    });
});
```

**The CSS:**

```
.soundIcnPlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.soundIcnPause {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**The jsFiddle Link:**

**[Live jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EdHK6/)**

What I have done is created a play effect onclick and similar pause effect on it.
I need to reverse it by making the audio play on page load and should pause on click and resume when clicked again.

Comment: Just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/EdHK6/1/? (warning: auto playing audio)

Comment: Excellent @Joe .. This is exactly what I was looking for. Please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Joe - I would be glad if you could post your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Hi @Joe. As you did not posted the answer, I have accepted the second best answer posted. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EdHK6/4/)**

Try this snippet,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = true;
    var audioEl = $('#player')[0]
    audioEl.play();
    $('a#button').click(function() {
        if(playing){
            playing = false;
            audioEl.pause();
            $(this).removeClass('soundIcnPlay').addClass('soundIcnPause');
        }else{
            playing = true;
            audioEl.play();
            $(this).removeClass('soundIcnPause').addClass('soundIcnPlay');
        }

    });
});
```

---

Other option is to add `autoplay` attribute to your `<audio>` tag.

```
<audio id="player" src="http://www.soundjay.com/ambient/check-point-1.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

Comment: Yes @Shaunak .. It works fine .. +1 for your efforts .. The issue: It is not changing the class and autoplay attribute also enables the audio skin. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, removed those lines for testing, added the updated code.

Comment: Yes. It works now, but I will go with Joe, as he answered first. If he doesn't post his answer, I shall accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing a `$('a#button').click()` after declaring the handler will do, but it's not an elegan solution. It would be better to declare a `playNow()` and `pauseNow()` functions and call them at the end of the ready handler.